# Acronym for a good JIRA ticket?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I saw an acronym for what makes a "good" JIRA ticket on wikipedia that I can't find it anymore.

It was something along the lines of quantifiable, actionable, defined, etc. The acronym did not actually spell out "JIRA."

Does anyone have a reference to the acronym I refer to? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you mean the acronym **S.M.A.R.T.**.
The single letters mean:

- **S**pecific
- **M**easurable
- **A**chievable
- **R**elevant
- **T**ime-bound

For more information, here is link to Wikipedia:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria